# JAX RS - Jersey file transfer, response should not redirect

Tags: javascript, jersey, jax-ws

I'm doing a filetransfer in JAX RS - With jersey multipart.
The problem is I don't quite get why the response makes the site change, I simple want the form like a normaly XHR request to stay on the site and then I'd like a way to get notified with a callback. But I can't find any way to do this?

HTML:

```
   <form action="resources/picture/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p>
            Select a Category : <select id="cat" name="cat"> <option value="1234">Icons</option></select>
        </p>
        <p>
            Select an image : <input type="file" name="file"/>
        </p>
        <input type="hidden" id="appId" name="appId" value="1"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload It" onclick=" NewPicture()" />
    </form>
```

JAX RS:

```
@POST
@Path("/upload/{pictureId}")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response overrideExistingFile(
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail,
        @PathParam("pictureId") Long pictureId) {
    Picture oldPicture = repository.get(Picture.class, pictureId);
    String uploadedFileLocation = oldPicture.getUrl();
    File file = writeToFile(uploadedInputStream, uploadedFileLocation, true);
    if (file != null) {
        System.out.println("File attempted saved @ " + file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    return Response.status(200).build();
}
```

Comment: what return in NewPicture() method in HTML file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solution of one of your problem that is redirection after uploading a file

if you dont want to redirect after uploading file than **remove return statement** from method `overrideExistingFile` and write void as a return type of that method.
like

```
public void overrideExistingFile(){
...
}
```

and still you want to get a notified than open a upload box in iframe and get notified using frame.parent without any redirection.